# Grouping, calculating, and sorting scoring data

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a list of lists, each list having "row id", "team name", "team number", "scout", "score":

```
teams = [[23L, u'team1', 5713L, u'Gange', 144L], 
 [22L, u'team3', 1406L, u'Gange', 126L], 
 [15L, u'team2', 7319L, u'Bob Loblaw', 90L], 
 [17L, u'team2', 7319L, u'Gange', 54L], 
 [18L, u'team1', 5713L, u'Bob Loblaw', 69L], 
 [16L, u'team3', 1406L, u'Bob Loblaw', 113L]]
```

I want to first group the data by the "team number" value, then get the min/avg/max of the "score" value by team. I can get all this information individually with pandas by using these functions:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(teams)
res.columns = ['id', 'name', 'number', 'scout', 'score']
print res.groupby('number')['score'].min()
print res.groupby('number')['score'].mean()
print res.groupby('number')['score'].max()

number
406      0
5703     9
7129    18
Name: score, dtype: int64

number
406      9.0
5703    22.5
7129    27.0
Name: score, dtype: float64

number
406     18
5703    36
7129    36
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

My problem is I want to keep all the original columns except score, effectively collapsing the rows into a single row for each team and the score column replaced with a list/tuple for min, avg, max values from the rows that have the same team, but to output this to a python object I can pass to a form, which I'm not sure if pandas is the best module for this.

I've looked at some samples with itertools, pandas, numpy, etc, but I'm going in circles now not sure how to approach the problem. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the desired output?  It isn't completely clear from your description.  You say that you want a single row for each team (with a tuple for score, no problem with that), but it looks like the existing team rows can have different values for **scout** within the same team (the first and fifth row for example).  How do you want to handle that?

Comment: good point, I should have mentioned that the scout wasn't important for the summarized data. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python comes with batteries included. You can use the power of [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/) from the [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sqlite3.html) module.

```
import sqlite3

teams = [[23L, u'team1', 5713L, u'Gange', 144L],
 [22L, u'team3', 1406L, u'Gange', 126L],
 [15L, u'team2', 7319L, u'Bob Loblaw', 90L],
 [17L, u'team2', 7319L, u'Gange', 54L],
 [18L, u'team1', 5713L, u'Bob Loblaw', 69L],
 [16L, u'team3', 1406L, u'Bob Loblaw', 113L]]

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create table t (id int, team_name text, team_number int, scout text, team_score int)");
cur.executemany("insert into t values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", teams)
con.commit()

res = cur.execute("""
  SELECT team_number, min(team_score), max(team_score), avg(team_score)
    FROM t
GROUP BY team_number""")

print "team_number, min, max, avg"
for row in res:
    print row
```

Output:

```
team_number, min, max, avg
(1406, 113, 126, 119.5)
(5713, 69, 144, 106.5)
(7319, 54, 90, 72.0)
```

Comment: actually now that I think about it, I should probably do all that logic in sql to begin with before I pull this data back to the app. I'll optimize that.